# Should we have a static final handler in utility class

Tags: android

I'm going to write a utility class for reporting error messages by posting messages via internet. So that it can be used by any classes and anywhere in the app. And I'm going to do like this:

```
public class Reporter {
    private static final Handler REPORTER_HANDLER = new Handler();

    private Reporter(){}

    public static void report(final Exception e) {
        REPORTER_HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Using HttpURLConnection to post the message to server.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Should I do like this, I think it's not a good idea, can someone tell me how to improve this code.

Comment: Why do you necessarily need `Handler` for?

Comment: You don't seem to understand the purpose of `Handler`.

Comment: @Tan Tran : You can do this using a Singleton class without Handler even. As you are just posting data to server

Comment: You not need to create new utility class. Just create method in Application class to send error report to server.

Comment: @Tan Tran Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are missing the concept of `Handler`. You do not need handler at all, at least in the use case you mention.

If you'd like to post some action to be some time later - handler would be appropriate.

If you'd like to perform some action on UI thread when your code is being run on other thread - handler would be appropriate.

But in your use case you just have to perform some operation, which doesn't need to interact with `Handler` at all.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I create Singletons:

```
public class Reporter {
    private static Reporter mReporter;

    public static initialize(){
        mReporter = new Reporter(); 
    }

    public static Reporter getSharedInstance(){
        return mReporter;
    }

    public void report(final Exception e) {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Using HttpURLConnection to post the message to server.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Initialize it once in your Applciation class or main Activity class:

```
Reporter.initialize();
```

Use it anywhere like this:

```
Reporter.getSharedInstance().report(e);
```